# Getting "syntax error near unexpected token `else’" in shell script

Tags: bash, shell, if-statement

I’m using bash shell on Amazon Linux.  When I run the below block of code

```
if [ $rc -eq 0 ] then
  passed=`tr ' ' '\n' < $TFILE | grep -c PASSED`
  error=`tr ' ' '\n' < $TFILE | grep -c ERROR`
  warning=`tr ' ' '\n' < $TFILE | grep -c WARNING`
  subject="Automated Results - $passed passed, $error errors, $warning warnings."
else
  subject="Failed to run any tests."
fi
```

I get the error, “syntax error near unexpected token `else’”.  What do I need to do to write this if-then-else block correctly?

Comment: BTW, http://shellcheck.net/ would find both this issue and others automatically.

Comment: As a further aside, if you're doing something like `foo; rc=$?; if [ $rc -eq 0 ]; then` -- don't, unless you have a compelling need for `$rc` elsewhere. Instead, just run `if foo; then`, and you avoid needing to capture the exit status at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To quote the syntax definition from `help if` in bash (which is quite close to the relevant POSIX spec):

```
if COMMANDS; then COMMANDS; [ elif COMMANDS; then COMMANDS; ]... [ else COMMANDS; ] fi
```

There can be multiple commands used in the conditional part of an `if` statement, **and a command separator (represented as a semicolon here) is mandatory** between the last of them and the list of commands to given should that conditional part return a successful status.

---

Comparing the code given against that syntax definition, it's missing such a separator:

```
if [ $rc -eq 0 ]; then
#               ^
#               \- this semicolon, or a newline, is mandatory before "then"
```

As it is, `then` is being passed as an argument to the `[` command, not parsed as syntax.

(Since you're tagged `bash`, consider also using native math syntax: `if (( rc == 0 )); then` is both more readable and less buggy).

Comment: You should also use double quotes when using variables everywhere. When `$rc` is empty or unset, it will cause syntax error: `if [  -eq 0 ]; then`

Comment: @VrataBlazek, of course that's true -- I'm strictly copying/pasting from the OP here, though, and to modify their code in any other respect during that demonstration would make the explanation of the most immediate issue less clear.

Comment: @VrataBlazek, ...which is why I suggested http://shellcheck.net/, which will report that bug, in the comments to the question previously.

Comment: @VrataBlazek, ...I'd also tend to suggest `[[ $rc -eq 0 ]]` or `(( rc == 0 ))` -- both of which provide contexts that eliminate the need for quoting to prevent string-splitting or glob expansion -- if explicitly targeting a ksh-derived shell such as bash.